Syncing tabs in custom tkinter
I have 2 frames with a set of tabs in each, the first set is a main view, the second set is options to filter and select what goes in the first set. I want the second set of tabs to change to the correct tab of options depending on the selected main tab.
This is what I have but I am not sure how to go about constantly checking it:
current_tab = main_frame_tabs.get()
if current_tab == "Upload Data":
    options_frame_tabs.set("Upload Options")
elif current_tab == "View Data":
    options_frame_tabs.set("View Options")
elif current_tab == "Trade Stats":
    options_frame_tabs.set("Stats Options")
else:
    pass

I tried a couple of setups with while loops but those are meant to end at some point and I need this to be checked continuously. I tried putting it in a function but don't really have a good way to constantly call it.

I found the answer myself after learning that I bind buttons to windows, I added a button bind to the main window that runs a function every time the left mouse button is clicked. Here is the main parts of the code to do this.
# Main application window
mainWindow = ctk.CTk()
mainWindow.title("AMTrading Dashboard")
mainWindow.geometry("1800x900")  # Set initial window size
ctk.set_appearance_mode('dark')  # Set dark mode by default
ctk.set_default_color_theme('dark-blue')  # Set dark blue color theme

mainWindow.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: on_click())

def on_click():
    current_tab = main_frame_tabs.get()
    if current_tab == "Upload Data":
        options_frame_tabs.set("Upload Options")
    elif current_tab == "View Data":
        options_frame_tabs.set("View Options")
    elif current_tab == "Trade Stats":
        options_frame_tabs.set("Stats Options")
    else:
        pass


If you are using CTkTabview module, you can simply set the command option to a function for main_frame_tabs:
def on_main_tab_changed():
    current_tab = main_frame_tabs.get()
    if current_tab == "Upload Data":
        options_frame_tabs.set("Upload Options")
    elif current_tab == "View Data":
        options_frame_tabs.set("View Options")
    elif current_tab == "Trade Stats":
        options_frame_tabs.set("Stats Options")

...

main_frame_tabs = ctk.CTkTabview(root, command=on_main_tab_changed)

Then whenever there is a tab change on main_frame_tabs, the function will be executed.
